# How can I reset the list by clicking the button from tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I was making a vocab test program and I was making a grading button. But I faced a problem that when I press the grading twice, `grade`, `entries`, `right`, `wrong` keeps appends and I can't find the way to reset these lists.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

window = tkinter.Tk()
container = tkinter.Frame(window)
canvas = tkinter.Canvas(container)
window.title('Rescue word test')
window.geometry('640x480')
window.resizable(True, True)
scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(container, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)

#scroll
main_frame = Frame(window)
main_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_canvas = Canvas(main_frame)
my_canvas.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

my_scrollbar = tkinter.Scrollbar(main_frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=my_canvas.yview)
my_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

my_canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=my_scrollbar.set)
my_scrollbar.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: my_canvas.configure(scrollregion= my_canvas.bbox("all")))

second_frame = Frame(my_canvas)

my_canvas.create_window((0,0), window= second_frame, anchor="nw")

def mouse_scroll(event):
    my_canvas.yview_scroll(-1 * int((event.delta / 120)), "units")
my_canvas.bind_all("<MouseWheel>", mouse_scroll)

def getEntry( i ):
    return list( second_frame.children.values() )[ i ]

Day21_eng = ['exquisite', 'acquisition', 'regulate', 'transportation', 'insight', 'straightforward', 'cultivate', 'innovation', 'preserve', 'odor', 'exception', 'munch', 'proclaim', 'slap', 'variability', 'investigate', 'flare', 'outpace', 'genuine', 'plead', 'fossilize', 'toil', 'drastic', 'withhold', 'inanimate', 'clockwise', 'amnesia', 'revive', 'theorize', 'culprit', 'limp', 'worn-out', 'indignity', 'span', 'bribe']
Day21_kor = [['우아한', '정교한', '절묘한'], ['취득', '획득', '습득'], ['규제하다', '통제하다'], ['운송', '운임', '추방'], ['통찰', '통찰력'], ['명확한', '솔직한'], ['경작하다', '기르다', '장려하다', '육성하다'], ['혁신'], ['보전', '보호지', '보호하다', '보존하다'], ['냄새', '악취', '기미', '낌새'], ['예외'], ['우적우적 먹다'], ['선언하다'], ['찰싹 때리다'], ['변화성', '가변성', '변용성'], ['조사하다'], ['불끈 성나게 하다', '이글거리다', '불꽃', '타오름'], ['앞지르다', '속도가 더 빠르다'], ['진짜의', '진품의'], ['탄원하다', '변호하다', '애원하다'], ['고착화하다', '화석화하다'], ['수고', '노고', '힘들게 일하다'], ['급격한', '극단적인'], ['보류하다', '유보하다'], ['생명 없는', '무생물의'], ['시계방향으로'], ['기억상실'], ['부활시키다', '되살아나게 하다'], ['이론화하다'], ['죄인', '범죄자', '장본인'], ['절뚝거리다', '느릿느릿 가다', '기운이 없는','축 처진'], ['닳아빠진', '진부한', '지친'], ['모욕', '무례', '치욕'], ['기간', '폭', '범위', '걸치다', '이르다'], ['뇌물을 주다', '뇌물']]

entries = []
grade =[]
def check():
    for i, e in enumerate(entries):
        value = e.get()
        grade.append(str(value in Day21_kor[i]))
    right = [i for i, value in enumerate(grade) if value == 'True']
    wrong = [k for k, value in enumerate(grade) if value == 'False']
    print(right) # I can check that these lists keep appends
    print(wrong)
    print(entries)
    print(grade)
    r = 0
    for i in range(0, len(right)):
        label_right = Label(second_frame, text='O', fg='Blue')
        label_right.grid(column=3, row= right[r])
        r += 1
    w = 0
    for i in range(0, len(wrong)):
        label_wrong = Label(second_frame, text='X', fg= 'red')
        label_wrong.grid(column=3, row= wrong[w])
        w += 1

b = 0
for row, item in enumerate(Day21_eng):
    global label_word 
    label_word = tkinter.Label(second_frame, text= item)
    label_word.grid(column=0, row=row)
    b += 1
    #입력 값 35개
    entry = tkinter.Entry(second_frame, width=30)
    entry.grid(row=row, column=1, sticky='nsew')
    # important to bind each one for access
    entry.bind('<Return>', getEntry)
    entries.append(entry) # save 'entry' into list
b_check = tkinter.Button(second_frame, text='grade', command=check)
b_check.grid(columnspan=2, row=36)

window.mainloop()
```

How can I reset these lists so I can re-grade the answers?
I've tried adding `right=[] wrong=[] entries=[] grade=[]` but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try resetting the list after grading.

```
def check():
for i, e in enumerate(entries):
    value = e.get()
    grade.append(str(value in Day21_kor[i]))
right = [i for i, value in enumerate(grade) if value == 'True']
wrong = [k for k, value in enumerate(grade) if value == 'False']
print(right) # I can check that these lists keep appends
print(wrong)
print(entries)
print(grade)
r = 0
for i in range(0, len(right)):
    label_right = Label(second_frame, text='O', fg='Blue')
    label_right.grid(column=3, row= right[r])
    r += 1
w = 0
for i in range(0, len(wrong)):
    label_wrong = Label(second_frame, text='X', fg= 'red')
    label_wrong.grid(column=3, row= wrong[w])
    w += 1
#-------------added part--------------
right=[]
wrong=[]
entries=[]
grade=[]
```

Comment: @tunatuna123 there are also more ways such as 1.making a button unavailable.